# change date format javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I need to send a date to a backend service that requires a date in the following format.

I have access to moment also.

I am using an input type of `datetime` on the front end which sends over a date like this: `"2017-05-17T10:00"`

**I have tried** `new Date("2017-05-17T10:00");` but this returns `Wed May 17 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`. I have also tried using some `moment` methods, but cannot get the correct format.

Does anyone know how I can convert the datetime string - `"2017-05-17T11:43"` to the following `'2017-05-17T10:43:03+0100'`?

Comment: "I have tried new Date("2017-05-17T10:00"); but this returns Wed May 17 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)" - That all seems right. What am I missing here?

Comment: @jamiec It should look like `'2017-05-17T10:43:03+0100'` but cannot figure out how to do this

Comment: you want to add the seconds and timezone to this input string `"2017-05-17T11:43"`? that seems odd, since you can't get the seconds if you don't have them and adding the timezone you could simply do by `str += '+0100'`. If you are trying to create a date on ISO format, i'm sure there are ways to do that

Comment: It *will* look like that, at `11:43:03 BST`. I still don't get the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `moment.format()`. Here is the list for reference https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```js
var dt = new Date("2017-05-17T10:00");
console.log(dt);

//'2017-05-17T10:43:03+0100'

var z = moment(dt).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ");
console.log(z);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date is [in ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If you have access to [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) (as you said) you can use format() method as below:

```
var date = moment("2017-05-17T10:00").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZZ");
console.log(date);
// prints "2017-05-17T10:00-0300"
```

[Try it.](https://jsfiddle.net/bfy8533v/3/)